# "ORA-00936: missing expression" Linked query to Oracle using OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, openquery

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY
(
    CLP,
    '
        SELECT *
        FROM ORACLE_TABLE
        WHERE [UPDATEDATE] > ''1900-01-01 12:00 AM''
    '
)
```

This query works fine when I remove the date criteria. But as soon as I try to pass this criteria it no longer works. I can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `[`and`]` and add convert date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY
(CLP, 
      '
         SELECT * 
         FROM ORACLE_TABLE 
         WHERE 
         UPDATEDATE > to_date(''1900-01-01 12:00'',''yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi'')
       '
)
```

or with `am`

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY
(CLP, 
      '
         SELECT * 
         FROM ORACLE_TABLE 
         WHERE 
         UPDATEDATE > to_date(''1900-01-01 12:00 AM'',''yyyy-mm-dd hh:miam '')
       '
)
```

Comment: Well, how do you think this would work if the `UPDATEDATE` column is of `DATE` datatype (which probably is the case)? it would probably be OK if the column is varchar2.

Comment: Run `select to_date(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:miam') from dual;` and check for yourself. It will entirely depend on the NLS date parameter you have!

Comment: `TO_CHAR` would make more sense than `TO_DATE`. Like `select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi am') from dual;`.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting the following error:
    "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string".

Comment: `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` field? But why? `TO_DATE` on a `VARCHAR` field makes sense. And OP already replied to your answer.

Comment: Ok so what I did was rather than do this on the actual date field I wrapped to_date around the passed in date string and that worked. I will edit the answer to reflect that and mark this as the answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Parado so you see spinon's edit... `TO_DATE` around a varchar makes more sense i.e. '1900-01-01 12:00' is a character string (varchar) field.

Comment: @spinon If it works for you, I'm glad i could helped you... a little :)

Comment: Wouldn't `12:00` without either `am` or `pm` be ambiguous? Perhaps the format should be `... hh:mi am` (and the timestamp supplied with `am` or `pm`). Alternatively, the time could be specified in the 24-hour format (and the format set, accordingly, as `... hh24:mi`).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY
(CLP,SELECT * FROM ORACLE_TABLE WHERE trunc(UPDATEDATE) > ''01-JAN-1900'')
```

All dates with no time component on them defaults to 12:00 AM (or 00:00 Hrs) in Oracle.

You can also use `to_timestamp(UPDATEDATE)` but for this to work the column should be of timestamp type (i.e. contain timestamp on it otherwise it would always give 12 AM). You can also use `to_char(UPDATEDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI AM')`.

Comment: This did work but I do need the date and time to be compared as I am trying to find records that were updated after a certain date and time.

Comment: Yeah it isn't a timestamp but just a regular date field. The to_date function worked out so long as it was around the right information. Thanks for your help though.